# How to transform the incremental json format data from a table into another table with tabular format

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In my Airflow ETL i am loading parquet files from AWS-S3 into Snowflake's table(raw_data) as a single column of type varient.
Now i want to transform that json format values from table raw_data into columnar format into another table.
Everyday when ETL runs it loads new parquet file from S3 into Snowflake's raw_data table. How can i run the transformation from this raw_data, so that it only takes the incremental data. As the raw_data has only one column of type varient. I am not able to figure out any logic which only considers the new rows.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a very common use-case.

The best-case scenario would be if you have a reliable timestamp column in your JSON. In that case, you don't have to modify your existing tables.

If you don't have such field, you can add a timestamp column to your `raw_data` table.

```sql
alter table raw_data add column added_at timestamp default current_timestamp::timestamp;
```

This timestamp column should be addressed in your destination table as well.

```sql
alter table target_data add column last_sync_at timestamp;
```

The real incrementally should live with your data transformation.

```sql
with transformed as (

  select
    json_column:top_level_json_key.lower_level_key::data_type as table_column_name,
    ...
    -- do this if you have a reliable incremental timestamp key
    json_column:record_generation_key::timestamp as last_sync_at
    -- or do this if you don't have this key
    added_at as last_sync_at

  from raw_data

  where
    last_sync_at > (select max(last_sync_at) from target_data)

)

select *
from transformed
```

Then, you only have to wrap the whole result in a merge/insert.

This is of course just a direction to think about. The real implementation completely depends on your use-case.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

This is the purpose of Snowflake Streams.  You create a stream over your raw_data table and it will tell you the incremental changes when new data is loaded.  When you run DML leveraging that stream, the stream will reset until new data is loaded to the raw_data table.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/streams.html